# Motion in 2D video sequence in computer vision

Tags: gradient-flows, computer-vision

I would compute the gradient of a video sequence. I have $x$, $y$, $t$ dimensions so I would obtain $dx$, $dy$, $dt$ referred to the all video sequence. I know that I have to use a *kernel filter* to calculate the gradient by $x$ and $y$, but I have doubt how to compute the $dt$... I read about *finite differences*, how can I apply it to my sequence?
I would also know, if it is correct to consider the sum of the $dx$ (i.e) of all frames, to have the total gradient of the video sequence (for the x dimension, and doing the same to calculate the y video gradient).
Is it?

thank you

**SOLUTION:**

Even if nobody was able to give me good answers (maybe for my bad formulation of the question) I find a solution to my problem that a want to share with you.

1) x-derivatives and y-derivatives can be computed by shifting Sobel filter in every frames of the video sequence. Than we can save every frame result.

2) t-derivatives (time gradient) can be computed by finite differences By following the notation:

t-derivative= frame at t = i+1 - frame at t=i where i=1,2,3,...,FrameSequenceNumber.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a whole field dealing with problems like this. Do you know something about convolution and discretization of partial differential operators?

Comment: yes I know something

Comment: It is a bit difficult to give a good answer if we don't know how much you know. :) But convolution and linear time invariant systems are like the most basic and important components.

Comment: The dt is basically just a partial derivative with respect to the third dimension. What may become complicated as the dimensions increase is to keep track in which order all the data points are stored to know how to apply the filters.

Comment: I know, but I wrote clear questions about my problem

Comment: There is usually no conceptual difference of computing a finite difference in spatial or temporal dimensions. Can vary if the image is indeed not captured in the same instant, but that is likely way overcourse if you are unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Think to your video as a function $\mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ and use $\partial_{u} f(x) = \frac{f(x+u)-f(x-u)}{2\|u\|}$ no matter what is $u$  ($(1,0,0)$ or $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$).